# OpenID Connect in c# for Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, google-oauth, openid-connect

Is there a way to implement Open Id connect in c# for Windows phone app.

I referred this site [OpenId Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#createxsrftoken) but here the implementation is in java,python.

I created a google+ authentication in my Windows phone app using this [OAuth2.0 for Mobile and Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) but I want to implement the same using OpenId Connect.

I am very new to this.Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can connect C# windows phone to googles openid server.  The main issue with this will be that you are going to have to code this all yourself.  To my knowlage there is no library created for google login for windows phone.  I know for a fact that the google .net client library does not support it.

The best place to start would be to check [openid connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) this will give you the information you need to implement this in your application.